# C - How fgets works with mutiple calls

Tags: c, file, fgets

I have the following code:

```
int i = 0;
char ar[500];

while(i < 20)
{
    printf("Type a line: ");
    fgets(ar, 500, stdin);
    fprintf(fp,"%s", ar);
    i++;
}
```

Basically, i am trying to open a file, then take 20 lines of input from the user and store it in an array, then print it to the file. It works fine but i don't understand how fgets works in the while loop. As i understand, when i = 0, fgets stores the 1st line to ar[500] and fprintf prints it out to the file, when i = 1, fgets stores the 2nd line to ar[500], but now ar[500] has 2 lines, but why fprintf only prints the 2nd line to the file but not all the 2 lines and so on when i increment by 1.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fgets always start populating the array at arr[0]. At every iteration, the previous line is overwritten. fgets will add the null terminating character for you in arr, so only the currently read line will be outputed to FILE pointed to by fp.

Answer (score 4):

The description of `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);`
 is [(C11 7.21.7p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2p2):

> 2 The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

The first character read by `fgets` will be always stored at `s[0]` and so forth up until at most `s[n - 1]` or the first newline character encountered (it being the last character stored). The element after the last character read will be set to `'\0'`, therefore terminating the string.

I.e. effectively a `fgets` call will overwrite `k + 1` first elements in the array where `k` is either the length of the line or `n`, whichever is smaller, and `1` means the null termination.

To store 20 lines, you'd need an array of arrays:

```
char ar[20][500];
```

then read into `ar[i]`.

Comment: When a while loop: while( fgets(ar, 500, fp) )  puts(ar); to read a file, each time fgets reads, it returns me a next line (Like the 1st time, fgets reads a the 1st line and puts prints it on screen and  the 2nd time, it returns  the 2nd line, puts prints it on the screen and so on). Do you know how fgets remember where it left.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen `fgets` does not, but `FILE`s have an inherent mechanism - **[file position indicator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p1)** that is moved forward as the file is being read.

Answer (score 3):

The buffer `ar` will be overwritten each time.

`fgets` has the prototype `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`. It will read a maximum of `n-1` characters from `stream` and write them to `str` and then adds the `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 0):

regarding: "but now ar[500] has 2 lines,"

NO, the function `fgets()` does NOT append.

Rather, it overlays.

In the posted code, always starting at `ar[0]`